# Is Quip LiveApp still maintained?

Tags: quip, liveapps

The documentation https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/1.x.x/guide/ seems quite dated, the cli doesn't work with updated versions of of Node & NPM and the most simplistic Hello world via quip-cli runs afoul of critical security issus.

Version: webpack 4.47.0
Time: 429ms
Built at: 03/26/2024 1:43:39 PM
1 asset
Entrypoint main = app.js
[25] multi ./src/root.jsx 28 bytes {0} [built]
[26] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
[48] ./src/root.jsx + 3 modules 8.79 KiB {0} [built]
| ./src/root.jsx 643 bytes [built]
| ./src/menus.js 3.03 KiB [built]
| ./src/model/root.js 1.92 KiB [built]
|     + 1 hidden module
+ 46 hidden modules

ERROR in app.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)